# Ошибка при парсинге значения width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пытаюсь сделать адаптивный слайдер, для этого я присваиваю всем оберткам слайдов ширину равную ширине экрана. Не могу понять почему JS выдает такую ошибку:

```
Ошибка при парсинге значения «width».  Потерянное объявление.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var pervSliderButton = document.querySelector('.js-slider__button_perv');
var nextSliderButton = document.querySelector('.js-slider__button_next');



window.addEventListener('resize', resizeSlide);

function resizeSlide() {
 console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
 var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper__slide');
 for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
 slides[i].style.width = document.body.clientWidth;
}

console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
}

.slider__wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 position: relative;
 width: 7680px;
}

.wrapper__slide {
 outline: 2px solid red;
}

.wrapper__slide img {
 width: 100%;
}

.wrapper__button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 8%;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
 transition: 0.1s;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper__button:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.slider__button_perv {
 left: 0;
}

.slider__button_next {
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="slider__wrapper">
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874100_1383101_25792ac067.jpg" alt="Слайд 1">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874104_1822794_cefef52967.jpg" alt="Слайд 2">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874108_2174295_2a76b9d678.jpg" alt="Слайд 3">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slide">
    <img src="http://storage4.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0404/h_1522874123_9925860_740e80c1e2.jpg" alt="Слайд 4">
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper__slider-position">
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_perv js-slider__button_perv"></div>
  <div class="wrapper__button slider__button_next js-slider__button_next"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @smellyshovel, зачем? Этот метод вроде как просто предоставляет стили для чтения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строку
`slides[i].style.width = document.body.clientWidth;`
исправьте на
`slides[i].style.width = document.body.clientWidth + 'px';`